# Trying to send message to specific channel, but can't define my client

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a command that clears a set amount of messages that works fine right now, but I'm trying to have the bot send a message to a log channel that tells the mods and admin, how many messages were deleted and who deleted them.
This is all the code right now from the clear file:

```
module.exports = {
name: 'clear',
description: "clears messages",
async execute(message, args){
    if(message.member.roles.cache.has('802911784892760074')){//If mod
        if(!args[0]) return message.reply('Enter amount');
        if(isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply('Enter amount');

        if(args[0] > 100) return message.reply('To high');
        if(args[0] < 1) return message.reply('To low');

        await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: args[0]}).then(messages =>{
            message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
            
            client.channels.cache.get('799292569825443860').send(`${message.author} has cleared ${args} messages!`)
        });
    }
}
```

This is the line of code that does not seem to be working:

```
client.channels.cache.get('799292569825443860').send(`${message.author} has cleared ${args} messages!`)
```

The command prompt says that the client is not defined, but I have the clientdefined in the main js file.

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
```

I'm still pretty new to this, and I may just be missing something very basic. (and I'm sorry if this question comes off as stupid to those who understand) any help would be awesome, as I seem to be at a roadblock here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `client` won't just magically appear in your command's file. You need to pass the `client` as an argument:

```js
async execute(message, args, client){
  // ...
```

And in `main.js`:

```js
commands.get('clear').execute(message, args, client)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your `client` object to the function, so for example you could do this:
`client.commands.get('clear').execute(message, args, client);` (or however you execute commands), and then have your function definition like this: `async execute(message, args, client){`